# How to insert or update a dbf file in a SQL Server 2005 trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I would like to insert or update a dbf file inside a after insert, update, delete trigger of SQL Server 2005.

I have come up with this

```
INSERT INTO openrowset('MSDASQL','Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceDB=C:\DBASE;SourceType=DBF','select * from persons')
SELECT 'coke','zero',4004
```

it works fine when I'm running it in SQL Server Management Studio or when I compile the trigger
but when I use our front end .NET program to update data an message box pops up saying

> The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSDASQL"
>   for linked server "(null)"

help pls? thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to update a DBF (dBase/FoxPro) file from a SQL Server ?? Why can't you just log your data into a SQL Server table....

Comment: my old program(front end application) is using dbf

Comment: but my back office application is using Sql server so i need to update my dbf everytime there are changes in sql. thanks

Comment: Does this really have to be "real-time", or couldn't you just extract the data e.g. once every hour or so, with a SSIS job??

Comment: nope it has to be in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I bumped into the same problem today.  Figure I'd post the resolution here for posterity.

The resolution came down to how I was connecting to the sql server.

In sql studio, are you connecting with a sql user account or a Windows user account?

I'd bet it's a sql user account, in which case the windows account under which the main sql server service runs is used to connect to the file system folder containing the DBF file(s).

When you connect to sql using a windows account, those windows credentials are used when attempting to write to the DBF file.

If you must connect with a Windows account check that the account has permissions to write to C:\DBASE